# 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports when uprade the traefik version in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

Today when I tried to upgrade traefik from 2.4.6 to 2.10.4, shows error like this:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
```

I only edit the version of traefik. this is the treafik deployment config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
  observedGeneration: 11
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2021-08-03T13:54:29Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-08-03T13:54:29Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2023-09-20T11:47:08Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-08-04T05:54:42Z'
      reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
      message: ReplicaSet "traefik-fb849d968" is progressing.
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
      app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
        helm.sh/chart: traefik-10.1.1
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2023-09-20T11:47:08Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:2.10.4
          args:
            - '--global.checknewversion'
            - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
            - '--entryPoints.metrics.address=:9300/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.web.address=:8000/tcp'
            - '--entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp'
            - '--api.dashboard=true'
            - '--ping=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus=true'
            - '--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint=metrics'
            - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
            - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              hostPort: 9300
              containerPort: 9100
              protocol: TCP
            - name: traefik
              hostPort: 9000
              containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: web
              hostPort: 8000
              containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: websecure
              hostPort: 8443
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsUser: 65532
            runAsGroup: 65532
            runAsNonRoot: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: traefik
      serviceAccount: traefik
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65532
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

I have already tried to kill the traefik pods and restart but did not fixed this issue. I also checked the port of host and all ports 9100,9000,8443 are free.